# Filter json based on items in an array

Tags: node.js, arrays, json

Given the following:

JSON Data: (rolesData)

```
{
"roles": [
    {
        "name": "Author",
        "filter": "XD-1"
    },
    {
        "name": "Administrator",
        "filter": "PL-8"
    },
    {
        "name": "Checker",
        "filter": "NH-3"
    },
    {
        "name": "Verifyer",
        "filter": "US-7"
    }
    ]
}
```

Filter data: (filterItems)

```
["US-7","PL-8"]
```

I want to return a rolesData data set filtered with matches on the filterItems, so in this example, I'd want back:

```
{
"roles": [
    {
        "name": "Administrator",
        "filter": "PL-8"
    },
    {
        "name": "Verifyer",
        "filter": "US-7"
    }
    ]
}
```

I've tried:

```
var result = rolesData.roles.filter(function (value) {
    return (value.filter.includes(filterItems));
});
```

If there is one item in filterItems, for example: "PL-8" I get back the required item, but how do I get all items with the matching filters?

Comment: You are very close. Just Reverse the includes function: `filterItems.includes(value)`.

Comment: for anyone else's benefit, @ISAE answer is nearly there:

var result = rolesData.roles.filter(function (value) {
    return filterItems.includes(value.filter);
});

Comment: Yeah, I missed the `.filter` :)